# Function to get top left and bottom right indexes of nonzero elements in an array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

So the goal is to write a function that gives the top left and bottom right indexes of a group of nonzero elements of an array. Two groups cant be next to eachother in the array. And if the group exist of just one element, the top left and bottom right indexes are the same. It was easy to get a function that gets all the indexes of nonzero elements, but I cant seem to filter it so just the top left and bottom right indexes remain.
Here is the function I already got:

```
import numpy as np
def get_indexes(A):
    M,N = A.shape
    pos = []
    for i in range(M):
        for j in range(N):
            if A[i,j]!=0:
                pos.append((i,j,A[i,j]))
    return pos
```

And here is an example of a given array:

```
A= np.array([[0, 7, 7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 7, 7, 0, 0, 9, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 7, 7, 0, 0, 9, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 7, 7, 0, 0, 9, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 7, 7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
[6, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 5, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])
```

I appreciate the help!

Comment: numpy also has a [`nonzero` function](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.nonzero.html) which you can use to get the nonzero elements. Are your array always 2D? You could consider them as an image and nonzero elements as *objects*. If that sounds good, I can help with that, but I am not sure if that's an *easy* way to do it.

Comment: yes the array is always 2D. I am awara of the nonzero function but thats not where I am stuck. I just need the top left and bottom right indexes of the nonzero elements

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I traversed on matrix in increasing order of for loop to find top left indexes of non-zero element, and to get bottom right indexes of non-zero element I traversed decreasing order of for loop.
Here the code:

```
import numpy as np

A= np.array([
[0, 7, 7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 7, 7, 0, 0, 9, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 7, 7, 0, 0, 9, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 7, 7, 0, 0, 9, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 7, 7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
[6, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 5, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])


def getting_top_left_indexes(A):
    break_condition = False
    M,N = A.shape
    pos = []
    for i in range(M):
        if break_condition == True:
            break
        for j in range(N):
            if A[i,j]!=0:
                pos.append((i,j,A[i,j]))
                break_condition = True
                break
    return pos

def getting_bottom_right_indexes(A):
    break_condition = False
    M,N = A.shape
    pos = []
    for i in range(M-1, 0, -1):
        if break_condition == True:
            break
        for j in range(N-1, 0, -1):
            if A[i,j]!=0:
                pos.append((i,j,A[i,j]))
                break_condition = True
                break
    return pos


top_left_indexes = getting_top_left_indexes(A)
bottom_right_indexes = getting_bottom_right_indexes(A)
```

**Edit:** I edited my answer regarding your explanation.
Here the updated code:

```
import numpy as np

A= np.array([
[0, 7, 7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 7, 7, 0, 0, 9, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 7, 7, 0, 0, 9, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 7, 7, 0, 0, 9, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 7, 7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
[6, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 5, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])

def get_indexes(A):
    M,N = A.shape
    pos = []
    for i in range(M):
        for j in range(N):
            if A[i, j] != 0:
                pos.append((i,j,A[i,j]))
    return pos

def filtering_indexes(indexes):
    filtered_list = []
    sorted_indexes = sorted(indexes, key=lambda x: x[-1])
    top_left_index = sorted_indexes[0]
    for i in range(0, len(sorted_indexes)):
        if sorted_indexes[i][2] == top_left_index[2]:
            pass
        else:
            filtered_list.append(sorted_indexes[i-1])
            top_left_index = sorted_indexes[i]
            filtered_list.append(top_left_index)

    if sorted_indexes[i][2] == top_left_index[2]:
        filtered_list.append(sorted_indexes[i])
    return filtered_list

indexes = get_indexes(A)
filtered_indexes = filtering_indexes(indexes)
```

Comment: yes is get what you try to do. But I need the indexes of each nonzero group, not just the one wich is most top left. I appreciate it though.

Comment: @V_Buffalo I thought we need to get top-left and bottom-right indexes. I updated my answer

Comment: @V_Buffalo You are welcome. If it helps, can you accept it as solution?

Answer (score 1):

Here is another idea to find the tops and bottoms. The idea is to use [`diff`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.diff.html) along both the rows and the columns on a [`pad`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.pad.html)ded version of A with 0. Once the tops found, iterate to find the bottoms with [`argmax`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.argmax.html#numpy.argmax) on the rest of the row or the column is 0 for each top.

```
#pad around A with 0s to avoid boundary effect
A_ = np.pad(A,((1,1),(1,1)),constant_values=0)

#get the position of the tops in A
tops = np.array(np.where((np.diff(A_, n=1, axis=1)[1:]>0) 
                          &(np.diff(A_, n=1, axis=0)[:, 1:]>0))).T
print(tops)
# [[0 1] # row 0, col 1 is the top of group 7
#  [1 5] # row 1, col 5 is the top of group 9
#  [5 6] # ...
#  [6 0]
#  [7 4]]

# get the bottom for each top 
bottoms = tops - 1 + np.array(
    [((A_[row_top:, col_top]==0).argmax(), 
      (A_[row_top, col_top:]==0).argmax())
     for (row_top, col_top) in (tops+1)]) #+1 is because A_ is padded version of A
print(bottoms)
# [[4 2] #row 4 col 2 is the bottom of group 7
#  [3 5] #...
#  [5 6]
#  [6 1]
#  [7 5]]
```

Depending on how you want the result, here is an array with the value of the group, assuming they are constant.

```
# create an array with all data with last column being the value of the group if necessary
res = np.hstack([tops, bottoms, A[tops[:,0], tops[:,1]][:,None]])
print(res)
# [[0 1 4 2 7] # group top at row 0 col 1 bottom at row 4 col 2 and value 7
#  [1 5 3 5 9] #...
#  [5 6 5 6 1]
#  [6 0 6 1 6] 
#  [7 4 7 5 5]]
```